# Why won't this code print? What is the error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, return

Why won't this code print? I am trying to write a method called min that takes 3 parameters and returns the smallest of the three values.

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        min(3, -2, 7);
        min(19, 27, 6);

    }

    public static void min(int number1, int number2, int number3){
        return Math.min(number1, Math.min(number2, number3));

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: What *is* the error? *Read* it. *Think* about it and, if asking a question, *say what it is*.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner, just started learning a week ago.  I really couldn't figure it out, but the answers really helped!

Comment: Make sure to *include* the error and/or problematic symptoms in questions. Don't ask people to guess "what the error is" as the compiler *says* what it is. (After stating the error, then it's must easier to explain *why* that error occurred - searching for the error message would also have found [*many* similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+unreachable+code).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not even compile as the line

```
System.out.println(); is after `return` statement,hence it is unreachable
```

Just print the value you are returning using this:-

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.println( min(3, -2, 7));
       System.out.println(min(19, 27, 6));

    }

    public static int min(int number1, int number2, int number3){
        return Math.min(number1, Math.min(number2, number3));


    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now. I'm a beginner at java so your response was really helpful!

Comment: `min()` should return *int* :P

Comment: @TheLostMind Yeah..u know I didnt test it on an IDE :p :)

Comment: @flyingseacows No issues.Everyone is a beginner once..Happy learning

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void min(int number1, int number2, int number3){
    return Math.min(number1, Math.min(number2, number3));

    System.out.println(); // The statement is unreachable (compilation error here). Next, you are not printing anything (which doesn't matter because it will not get executed)
}
```

Solution: print the answer in `main()` method like this : `System.out.println(min(3, -2, 7));` and return `int` from `min()`

Comment: Actually, the code doesn't even compile, because of the unreachable statement, so I'm not sure the `Next, you are not printing anything` part is correct

Comment: First answer should be `your code not compile at least. `

Answer (score 1):

Your code not even compile

```
public static void min(int number1, int number2, int number3){ // return type is void
    return Math.min(number1, Math.min(number2, number3)); // and you return
```

This is not a valid code at least if your method has a return type as

```
 public static double min(int number1, int number2, int number3){ 
    return Math.min(number1, Math.min(number2, number3)); // method will exit from here
    // and return the value to caller
    System.out.println(); // never reach this line
 }
```

Comment: OH! Thank you, I didn't notice I had put void. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can not add any statement after the `return` statement. It is a rule in Java. `return` statement should be the last statement of any method. Therefore first of all remove the `System.out.println();` from the the `min()`.

According to your question, you are calling the `min()` and do not send result of the methods into output stream to print on the console. That is why you can not see the result.

You have to call the `min()` inside of the `System.out.println()`. then you can see the result. Also you have to convert the return type of your function `min()` as `int`.

Good Luck!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks.  I was sort of confused as to how the return statement is used, but this helped clear it up.